# Ivy: configuration doesn't exist

Tags: java, ant, ivy

When trying to make an Ivy dependency part of configuration, by adding the property `conf="widget->default"` to a `dependency` declaration, I get the error:

> Problem occurred while parsing ivy file: Cannot add dependency 'com.acme.widget#widget;1.2.3' to configuration 'widget' of module org.foo#bar;working@localhost.localdomain because this configuration doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

Each configuration must be explicitly declared in the `configurations` section of the same Ivy module file which declares the dependencies.  For example:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="widget" description="widget JAR files"/>
</configurations>
```

See the [Ivy documetntation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ivyfile/configurations.html) and the   [example `ivy.xml` file from the Ivy tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/tutorial/conf.html) for more details.